# ISIM only simulates until 61.215.000 picoseconds

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx

Despite me setting any interval my simulation only runs that long using the built-in ISIM simulator.
Even if I run the simulator, rerun the simulation and/or take small steps it stops there.

Is there anything I can do? It started doing it without any reason whatsoever.

Please advise if I should upload any code should that help.

Using ISE 14.7 on Windows 8.1.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to the minimum that can reproduce the problem, and then show that code; unless you in the process discovers the problem yourself, which is very likely ;-)  One thing to look for is an infinite loop, thus one where the exit condition is never true, since the simulator will then hang forever in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run simulations much longer than this in ISIM, so this points at your code, I think.

Two ways forward:

1. Try another simulator, perhaps ghdl (free) and see if it reports a problem that ISIM doesn't. It is usually stricter (more standard compliant) than ISIM and can sometimes diagnose problems ISIM can't.

[ghdl is available here...](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/)

2. Split your design up, delete subunits one at a time until simulation runs properly. In other words, divide and conquer. Then focus on the last subunit you deleted...

This approach also leads you towards Morten's suggestion, but often you find the trouble yourself before you get there...

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find my issue. Apparently I indexed out of a vector.

Comment: Ah yes. If you can reproduce the problem now, turn ISIM's runtime checks ON and try again; it should diagnose the trouble much more easily.